# Heat press of vinyl on 100% polyester fabric

Tags: materials, heat-treatment

I want to customise a piece of fabric that is 100% polyester (exclusive of decorations, wash at 30º) with vinyl. My idea is to use a vinyl cutter (such as Silver Bullet) to cut a pattern on the sheet, remove the background, transfer to a transfer sheet, and use a heat press to adhere the design to the fabric.

I have seen good results of this method on cotton and I am not sure if a heat press would work on polyester.

How can I transfer a digital design onto 100% polyester fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another similar shirt, 100% polyester, to see if it could work. I found the maximum temperature for polyester at [this page](https://www.thespruce.com/select-correct-ironing-temperature-for-fabrics-2146186):

> ### Iron Setting Temperatures in Celsius and Fahrenheit
>
> If your iron uses a different scale or you want to know more exacting temperatures for ironing different types of fabric, follow these guidelines:
>
> ...
>
> - Polyester: 148 C/300 F

I found duration for heat pressing [at this page](http://wiki.makespace.org/Equipment/TShirtPress):

> Suggested settings: temp=160 time=16 (seconds). Varies with different vinyls.

So I used 20 seconds at 148ºC. I cut the design by hand or on a Silver Bullet Vinyl Cutter. The result works very well:

[image: First shirt with hand-cut design]

[image: Second shirt with computer-cut design]